# Diagonalizing two real symmetric matrices with one $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, I would like to know if it is possible to find a single $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ matrix $M$ such that both $MAM^T$ and $(M^{-1})^TBM^{-1}$ are diagonal.

There are certainly enough parameters in an $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ matrix to make this possible. Simple counting gives $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-(n^2-1)=n+1\leq 2n$. So in principle this should work unless something very special happens. $n=1$ is trivial, and I have worked out that it is possible in the $n=2$ case. **Edit** (I have since realized I was working out the wrong problem with the $n=2$ case)

This seems well suited for a proof by induction, but I can't figure out where to start!

**Edit**

While I have accepted @user8675309 's answer, I'd like to add here the conditions for which such an $M$ can be found. As per @WillJagy 's reference, there is a theorem which states that if we have $A$ and $B$ with $B$ invertible, then $MAM^T$ and $MBM^T$ are diagonal for some nonsingular $M$ if and only if $C=B^{-1}A$ is diagonalizeable.

The case that I am asking about can be turned into this one by considering $A$ and $B^{-1}$ instead. Therefore my condition that both $MAM^T$ and $(M^{-1})^TBM^{-1}$ are diagonal is possible if and only if $C=BA$ is diagonalizeable.

If we take @user8675309 's counter example, we see that their $BA$ is not diagonalizeable.

Comment: Such things are done nicely in Horn and Johnson; I have the first book, Matrix Analysis. I will look for your item

Comment: table 4.5.15T on page 229, it can be done if one is invertible, this is case IIb. the method begins in the middle of page 231, to the middle of page 232. He does refer to Takagi's factorization (4.4.4) for this method, stated as corollary on page 204 and proved in half page 205. I went through it once, I think I decided that the call to use Takagi could be worked around.

Comment: I will read how such a proof works, thank you for the reference it is very helpful! Do you expect a similar result to hold for the case I am asking? Where $A$ and $B$ transform "oppositely".

Comment: no idea. See what happens in your problem when the matrix $B$ is already diagonal with just $1,0,-1$ allowed on the main diagonal.

Comment: This form of simultaneous diagonalisation by congruence is strange. Would you please explain the motivation of this problem?

Comment: @user1551 could be from his physics questions, latest https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/585207/vev-implying-symmetry-breaking-but-unable-to-pick-out-specific-subgroup  Just guessing

Comment: @WillJagy precisely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit, much shorter rationale:**
The claim can't be true even if we allow $M\in GL\big(n,\mathbb C\big)$.  The reason simply is it implies
$M\big(AB\big)M^{-1}= \big(MAM^T\big)\big( M^{-T}BM^{-1}\big) = D_1D_2=D$
i.e. it implies the product of two real symmetric matrices $A,B$ is always diagonalizable.  Yet if we select $A$ to be the $2\times 2$ ones matrix and $B$ to be the (diagonal) reflection matrix, then $\text{rank}\big(AB\big)=1$ and $\text{trace}\big(AB\big)=0$ which means $\big(AB\big)$ is defective and contradicts the existence of $M$.

**original response below:**
*Suppose for contradiction that the statement is True*
Then $\big(MAM^T\big)= D_1$ and $\big( M^{-T}BM^{-1}\big)=D_2$.

$$
\begin{align}    
M\big(AB\big)M^{-1}\\   
&=\big(MAM^T\big)\big( M^{-T}BM^{-1}\big) \\  
&=D_1D_2\\ 
&=D_2D_1\\  
&=\big( M^{-T}BM^{-1}\big)\big(MAM^T\big)\\  
&=M^{-T}\big(BA\big)M^{T}\\
\end{align}
$$
multiplying on the left by $M^T$ and the right by $M^{-T}$ implies
$\big(M^TM\big)\big(AB\big)\big(M^{T}M\big)^{-1} =\big(BA\big)$

Suppose $A$ is singular and $B$ is invertible but indefinite.  This should raise alarm bells since $\big(AB\big)$ and $\big(BA\big)$ are similar through $B$ yet $B \neq M^TM$.  To make this explicit:  select $A:=\mathbf{11}^T$ and $B:=\bigg[\begin{array}\\ 
1  &0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\bigg]$

multiplying each on the left by $A$ gives
$ \mathbf {11}^T\big(M^TM\big)\big(\mathbf {11}^TB\big)\big(M^{T}M\big)^{-1} =\mathbf {11}^T\big(B\mathbf {11}^T\big)$
since $M \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, we have $M\mathbf 1 = \mathbf v\neq 0$ and $0\lt\alpha = \big \Vert \mathbf v\big \Vert_2^2$.  Finally, computing the rank of each side of the equality gives us

$$
\begin{align}    
1\\
&=\text{rank}\Big(\alpha\cdot \mathbf {1}\mathbf 1^T\Big)\\   
&=\text{rank}\Big(\mathbf {1}\big(\mathbf v^T\mathbf v\big) \mathbf 1^T\Big)\\
&=\text{rank}\Big(\mathbf {1}\big(\mathbf 1^TM^T\big)\big(M\mathbf 1\big) \mathbf 1^T\Big)\\      
&=\text{rank}\Big(\mathbf {11}^T\big(M^TM\big)\big(\mathbf {11}^T\big)\Big)\\   
&=\text{rank}\Big(\mathbf {11}^T\big(M^TM\big)\big(\mathbf {11}^T\big)B\Big)\\   
&=\text{rank}\Big(\mathbf {11}^T\big(M^TM\big)\big(\mathbf {11}^TB\big)\big(M^{T}M\big)^{-1}\Big)\\   
&=\text{rank}\Big(\mathbf {11}^TB\mathbf {11}^T\Big)\\  
&=\text{rank}\Big(\mathbf 0\Big)\\ 
&= 0  
\end{align}
$$

and we conclude $1=0$ which is a contradiction

Comment: $$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&3 \\
9&3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&0 \\
0&-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&9 \\
3&3 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
-8&0 \\
0&72 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: $$
\left(
\frac{-1}{24}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3&-3 \\
-9&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&1 \\
1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\frac{-1}{24}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3&-9 \\
-3&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\frac{1}{576}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0&0 \\
0&64 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: apparently he had $M$ and $M^{-1}$ on opposite sides, hmmm.......

Comment: Alright, the 2 by2 case does fail with the reversed order. Not sure the OP typed what he intended, except that he did comment "transform oppositely." Perhaps he will return and clarify the matter within 24 hours

Comment: @WillJagy not only is 'transform oppositely' mentioned but if you check the edit logs, OP originally wrote $MAM^T$ and $M^{-1}B(M^{-1})^T$ both diagonal, then 2 hours later (with your original and perhaps subsequent comment sandwiched in between), the original post was edited by OP to say $MAM^T$ and $(M^{-1})^TBM^{-1}$ both diagonal.  An hour after that I answered.  As far as I'm concerned the conjecture has been asked and answered.  It is **false**.

Comment: I can see there was some editing. Not a good sign. I think I was right to say I had no idea and wander away.

Comment: Yes, I gave no attention to what the OP actually asked. I just gave some pages in a book I like, he said that seemed a nice reference, I figured that was enough for now. If he spends a little time on Horn and Johnson he will be able to ask a more sensible question. Well, someday

Comment: Yes, my apologies for misleading you both. I had confirmed the $n=2$ case for my original question (the one before the edit), but subsequently realized what I cared about was the case that @user8675309 answered. I consider the question answered.

Comment: By the way, I just have to compliment you on your name @user8675309.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $B$ is invertible and $C=B^{-1}$. Then $MAM^T$ and $MCM^T$ are diagonal. This means $A$ and $C$ are always simultaneously diagonalisable by the usual kind of congruence whenever $A$ is symmetric and $C$ is both invertible and symmetric. But this is known to be false. E.g. if we take user8675309's counterexample, we have $MAM^TMCM^T=MCM^TMAM^T$. Therefore $AM^TMC=CM^TMA$ and $C^{-1}AM^TM=M^TMAC^{-1}$, i.e. $SAC^{-1}$ is symmetric for some positive definite matrix $S=M^TM$. However,
$$
S=\pmatrix{a&b\\ b&c}\Rightarrow
SAC^{-1}=\pmatrix{a&b\\ b&c}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}=\pmatrix{a+b&-a-b\\ b+c&-b-c}.
$$
It is symmetric only when $a+c=-2b$. But then $\det(S)=ac-b^2=ac-\frac14(a+c)^2=-\frac14(a-c)^2\le0$. Therefore $S$ isn't positive definite, which is a contradiction. Hence $A$ and $C$ are not simultaneously diagonalisable by congruence.