# Diagonalize two real symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume A and B are two real symmetric matrices of same order, what is the criteria to guarantee that there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $A=QDQ^T$ and $B=Q^T\tilde{D}Q$, where $D$ and $\tilde{D}$ are two diagonal matrices.

Note that, if we instead required $B = Q\tilde{D}Q^T$, then this condition is simultaneous diagonalization of $A$ and $B$, which is equivalent to $A$ and $B$ commuting, or equivalently, $AB$ being symmetric. I am wondering if there's a similar characterization for when $B$ is diagonalized by $Q^T$, rather than $Q$.

Comment: Simultaneous diagonalisation occurs if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute (i.e. $AB = BA$), which occurs if and only if $AB$ is symmetric.

Comment: Yes, I know the criteria of simultaneous diagonalization, but the question I asked is not this.

Comment: Right, sorry, I do see the difference now. I would advise editing your question to say that you know about simultaneous diagonalisation, and point out exactly how your question is different. You should read our [guidelines for asking questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), particularly the part about providing context. Highlighting how this is different from the standard problem is excellent context for your question.

Comment: Thank you for reminding.

Comment: I just submitted a suggested edit to add a bit more context, which I think will make your question received more positively. If you don't like it, feel free to reject the edit, or roll back to the previous version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: note if $Q$ exists, it may be chosen to have determinant 1.  This post is somewhere between a duplicate and a specialization of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3868605/diagonalizing-two-real-symmetric-matrices-with-one-sln-mathbbr-transforma/